# How to write Tensorflow dataset to disk and restore it later?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have a TF dataset that has been prepared by doing some complex preprocessing as part of a separate process. Now, I would like to save it to disk and read it later.

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `tf.data.experimental.save`